# How do I add a file extension to an extentionless file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files in a folder that do not have extenstions.

I do know the extension that they should be.  Example:

Folder Structure: C:\temp\sugar\example-pdf-file  (no extension)

I am running the following script:

```
Clear-Host
$dir = "C:\temp\sugar"
$ext = ".pdf"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir

foreach ($file in $files){
    Write-Host $file.BaseName #returns "example-pdf-file"
    Write-Host $file.Extension # returns NULL
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($file.FullName.$ext)
}
```

Having ran the above, an error is returned saying:

`Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is null.`

I believe that Rename-Item isn't made for this specific task and I can't find what is.

Please help!

Comment: Change `($file.FullName.$ext)` to `"$($file.FullName).${ext}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that Rename-Item isn't directly suited for this task because it expects a complete file name including the extension for the -NewName parameter. Here is the script.

```
$dir = "C:\temp\sugar"
$ext = ".pdf"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir

foreach ($file in $files){
    # Construct the new file name by appending the extension to the base name
    $newName = $file.FullName + $ext
    
    # Rename the file
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is trying to expand the property `.FullName.pdf` in your code and, since `.FullName` is a string, it has no `.pdf` property:

```bash
$file = New-Item example-pdf-file -ItemType File
$file.FullName.$ext # => Is null
```

You need to construct the string manually:

```bash
foreach ($i in $file) {
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName "$($file.FullName)$ext"
}
```

Though, I would recommend you to rename the files using a [delay-binding scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.4#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters):

```bash
$ext = '.pdf'
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File |
    Where-Object { -not $_.Extension } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + $ext }
```